# Linear Discriminant Analysis classifier interpretation

Tags: classification, discriminant-analysis, interpretation

Hi I am using Linear Discriminant Analysis (LDA) to solve binary classification problem. After fitting, I can get the projection matrix and class means.

I am just wondering how can I turn that into useful interpretation? For instance, in linear regression, I can measure how the change of value in a variable impact the predicted value or in tree where I can inspect the variables for splitting. Similarly, how can I do it here?

My guess would be the class A have this means `MA_1` in feature1 while the means of feature 1 in class B is `MB_1`. Similarly in feature 2 and so on and so forth. If so, how is the projection matrix comes into play here? Or maybe the means are relative to the projection matrix?

Thanks!